# Help with MySQL Coalesce and Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, coalesce

I'm (attempting) to write a MySQL stored procedure that parses a large text file.  Part of what this procedure does is check to see if the entities (in this case, government contractors) named in each record are already contained in the db.  (This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971965/import-and-process-text-file-within-mysql).)  This is my first stored procedure and so I'm sure I've wondered off the rails here, and I would appreciated any help.

Here's what I have right now (after declaring the variables):

```
-- try and fetch first organization (a government agency)
SET agency = COALESCE(SELECT org_agency_o_id FROM orgs_agencies WHERE org_agency_code = maj_agency_cat,SELECT min(org_id) FROM orgs WHERE org_name LIKE CONCAT('U.S. ',SUBSTRING(maj_agency_cat,5)))
-- check to see if that worked  
IF agency = NULL THEN 
    INSERT INTO orgs (org_name,org_name_length,org_type,org_sub_types) VALUES (CONCAT('U.S. ',SUBSTRING(maj_agency_cat,5)),LENGTH(CONCAT('U.S. ',SUBSTRING(maj_agency_cat,5))),'org','Org,GovernmentEntity,Federal,Agency');
    SET agency = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF; 
-- try and fetch second organization
SET org = COALESCE(SELECT MIN(org_id) FROM orgs WHERE org_name IN (vendorname, vendoralternatename, vendorlegalorganizationname, vendordoingasbusinessname), SELECT MIN(org_alias_org_id) FROM orgs_aliases WHERE org_alias in (endorname, vendoralternatename, vendorlegalorganizationname, vendordoingasbusinessname)) 
IF org = NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO orgs(org_name,org_name_length,org_type,org_sub_types,org_created) VALUES (vendorname,LENGTH(vendorname),'org','org',DATE());
    SET org = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF
```

Right now MySQL is throwing an error on the line:

```
SET agency = COALESCE(SELECT org_agency_o_id FROM orgs_agencies WHERE org_agency_code = maj_agency_cat,SELECT min(org_id) FROM orgs WHERE org_name LIKE CONCAT('U.S. ',SUBSTRING(maj_agency_cat,5)))
```

'maj_agency_cat' is a variable that I declare at the beginning of the procedure and then is assigned dynamically using a cursor that goes through my staging data.  The full stored procedure can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/RZv4U3w3).

I'm sure I'm missing something basic and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping another `()` around the inner `SELECT` statements in your `COALESCE` arguments.  Otherwise, they are not treated as subqueries to be executed first and the value returned, but as query objects passed into `COALESCE`, which is not a valid argument type for `COALESCE`:

```
 SET agency = COALESCE((SELECT ..), (SELECT ..))
```

Comment: Great thanks!  Now I need to figure out what's wrong with my IF statements.

Comment: @tchaymore: You need to use `IF org IS NULL`.  You can't compare to `NULL` directly, it will never work.

Comment: That makes sense but still throwing an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF agency IS NULL THEN 
   INSERT INTO orgs (org_name,org_name_length,org_type,' at line 53

Comment: I thought I should post a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983600/mysql-if-then-statements-in-stored-procedures.  If you have the time, and the answer, please take a look.