# Has anyone tried the new MySQL 5.5 InnoDB for performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, isam

I would like to know if anyone has personally benchmarked the new InnoDB with large data sets.

I don't use the latest version but I have implemented ISAM tables with over 20 million records. It's well indexed and I am able to pick out on a given condition, about 10K records in less than 10 seconds. But my issue is that it won't do to good with new inserts since the index has to be rebuilt.

I read that the new InnoDB engine is really fast with ACID Transactions.

BTW, the DB is going to be constantly read by many users and also new entries may coming in frequently.

Has anyone really tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the innodb plugin as I've always found the standard innodb engine to be perfectly perfomant, especially for reads. Not sure why people think myisam is more performant than innodb - it's a conundrum wrapped in an enigma.

**Previous answers**

- 500 million rows query runtimes of 0.02 seconds

  [MySQL and NoSQL: Help me to choose the right one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601)
- 60 million rows query runtimes of 0.34 seconds

  [60 million entries, select entries from a certain month. How to optimize database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451190/60-million-entries-select-entries-from-a-certain-month-how-to-optimize-database/5451389#5451389)
- 125 million rows query runtimes of 0.7 seconds

  [How to avoid "Using temporary" in many-to-many queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472241/how-to-avoid-using-temporary-in-many-to-many-queries/5473513#5473513)
- 100 million rows...

  [Optimal MySQL settings for queries that deliver large amounts of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129071/optimal-mysql-settings-for-queries-that-deliver-large-amounts-of-data/4144514#4144514)

**More interesting stuff**

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html
- http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/03/18/video-the-innodb-storage-engine-for-mysql/
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/12/03/mysql-50-51-and-innodb-plugin-cpu-efficiency/
- http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reasons-to-use-innodb-plugin

Comment: As of mysql 5.5, InnoDB is the default. It's not a plugin. Further, before the SUN takeover of MySQL, I was in the presence of the co-founder of MySQL, David Axmark during his visit. Then ISAM was the way to go for large, read-only DBs. This is why wanted to know if anyone has had first-hand exposure to this matter. And looking at the stats you've given, I guess InnoDB makes sense now :) Thanks!

Comment: yea misred his question thought he was talking about the innodb plugin which is a replacement for the standard innodb engine. http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reasons-to-use-innodb-plugin Neverthless, my answer is standard innodb engine related :)

Comment: How to create a `InnoDB` plugin for `MySQL` 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

Percona just had a session on InnoDB in 5.5 at their last seminar. You can download the slides for "Migrating From MyISAM to InnoDB" here (http://www.percona.com/live/nyc-2011/schedule/sessions/).

They have fixed a lot of things in 5.5 that increase performance and resolve a lot of issues so it can better take advantage of the hardware. Performance is still highly reliant on memory allocation though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've seen the white paper myself (released today). But I was more keen on first hand experiences. +1 for your slides link.