# Speed up search query (large junction table)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, junction

I'm writing a multistore webshop application in PHP/MYSQL. The products table has about a million records, currently i'm having 5 stores with all products in it and about 3 stores with a few products. The product's price sometimes varies from store to store. Because it should be possible to add or delete certain products for let's say only shop 2, i created a junction table. My tables looks like this:

```
products(id,name,description,price,media) ~1M records
stores(id,name)
products_stores(id,product_id,store_id,price) ~5M records
```

When searching for products the query takes about 20 seconds. I added indices to products(name,description) + products_stores(product_id,store_id). Is there any way I could speed up the process? Most of the records in products_stores are the same (except for the store_id), but I'd like to keep it flexible.

The query:

```
SELECT 
  Product.id, 
  Product.name, 
  Product.drager, 
  Product.import, 
  Product.price, 
  Product.description, 
  Product.units 
FROM 
  products AS Product 
INNER JOIN 
  products_stores AS ProductStore ON (
    ProductStore.product_id = Product.id 
    AND 
    ProductStore.store_id =1
  ) 
WHERE 
  name LIKE 'bach%' 
ORDER BY 
  Product.description asc 
LIMIT 
  500
```

I added a FULLTEXT index on only name and deleted the ORDER BY statement, but it seems to make no difference. My indices are now:

```
Products(name) BTREE
Products(name,description) FULLTEXT
Products(name) FULLTEXT
```

EXPLAIN of the above query gives: (with indices)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fe8C.gif

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: can you show us the query that takes 20 seconds?

Comment: sure, I added the query.

Comment: You are allowed to put line breaks in queries. It may make your life easier to do so. :)

Comment: Have you check if MySQL take index ( query execution plan: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html )

Comment: Please, post create table products. Only to see datatypes. Is name or description a 'Text' type? Then you should use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sort_length

Comment: I can't believe we all forgot to ask this, but can you post the output of `EXPLAIN` for your query?

Comment: Yes, throw an explain at the beginning of that query and post the output. That'll tell us a lot more.

Comment: What indexes do you have in the `ProductStore` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the following links about clustered primary keys:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/

[MySQL and NoSQL: Help me to choose the right one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601)

[Any way to achieve fulltext-like search on InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732067/complex-query-for-recreating-fulltext-search-effect-on-innodb/4732982#4732982)

[How to avoid "Using temporary" in many-to-many queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472241/how-to-avoid-using-temporary-in-many-to-many-queries/5473513#5473513)

[60 million entries, select entries from a certain month. How to optimize database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451190/60-million-entries-select-entries-from-a-certain-month-how-to-optimize-databas/5451389#5451389)

then redesign your product_stores table something along the lines of:

```
create table products_stores
(
store_id int unsigned not null,
product_id int unsigned not null,
...
primary key (store_id, product_id)
)
engine=innodb;
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for products from a specific store, I would have an index on the store ID AND the Name, then adjust the query to pre-qualify the products FROM the given store instead of looking at all products first.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      P.id, 
      P.name, 
      P.drager, 
      P.import, 
      P.price, 
      P.description, 
      P.units 
   FROM 
      Product_Stores PS
         JOIN Products P
            on PS.Product_ID = P.ID
           AND P.Name like 'back%'
   WHERE
      PS.Store_ID = 1
   order by
      P.Description
   limit
      500
```